# Wrap a pre-trained pytorch model into torch.nn.Module class

Tags: python, pytorch, torchscript

I want to learn how to convert pytorch model into TorchScript. To do that I have to define a torch.nn.Module class that wraps the model first.

I use HuggingFace Diffusers or Transformers class to wrap the models and convert into TorchScript before. I want to know how to define the wrapper class myself. If I have only the downloaded pytorch model, is it possible to define a wrapper class? Or is there anything I have to know?

Below is my code for a downloaded pre-trained model.

```py
import torch

PATH = 'model.pth'
pretrained_dict = torch.load(PATH)

for key in list(pretrained_dict.keys()):
    print(key)

class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return 0

model = MyModel()
model.load_state_dict(pretrained_dict)
model.eval()
example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224) 
torch_script = torch.jit.trace(model, example_input)
```

output:

```bash
tok_embeddings.weight
norm.weight
output.weight
layers.0.attention.wq.weight
layers.0.attention.wk.weight
layers.0.attention.wv.weight
layers.0.attention.wo.weight
layers.0.feed_forward.w1.weight
layers.0.feed_forward.w2.weight
layers.0.feed_forward.w3.weight
layers.0.attention_norm.weight
layers.0.ffn_norm.weight
layers.1.attention.wq.weight
layers.1.attention.wk.weight
layers.1.attention.wv.weight
layers.1.attention.wo.weight
layers.1.feed_forward.w1.weight
layers.1.feed_forward.w2.weight
layers.1.feed_forward.w3.weight
layers.1.attention_norm.weight
layers.1.ffn_norm.weight
layers.2.attention.wq.weight
layers.2.attention.wk.weight
layers.2.attention.wv.weight
layers.2.attention.wo.weight
...
layers.31.feed_forward.w3.weight
layers.31.attention_norm.weight
layers.31.ffn_norm.weight
rope.freqs


--> 17 model.load_state_dict(pretrained_dict)
     18 model.eval()
     19 example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224) 

File ~/text-generation-webui-main/installer_files/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:2041, in Module.load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   2036         error_msgs.insert(
   2037             0, 'Missing key(s) in state_dict: {}. '.format(
   2038                 ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in missing_keys)))
   2040 if len(error_msgs) > 0:
-> 2041     raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
   2042                        self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   2043 return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for MyModel:
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "tok_embeddings.weight", "norm.weight", "output.weight", "layers.0.attention.wq.weight", "layers.0.attention.wk.weight", "layers.0.attention.wv.weight", "layers.0.attention.wo.weight", "layers.0.feed_forward.w1.weight", "layers.0.feed_forward.w2.weight", "layers.....
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict` is a reserved word for the type of dictionaries. You should call your parameters dictionary `state_dict` or something like that instead.

Comment: I updated the variable name but it still got error. Updated as my post. 
I think I want to know is how to declare the wrapper class from a pre-trained model file.

Comment: I think this should be a comment not an answer to OP's question. It does not resolve the issue, it's just pointing out the obvious incorrect submodule being called.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Valentin Goldité pointed out, it's `state_dict`.

However, the other issue is that you're re-defining `MyModel` and then you're trying to `load` the `state_dict` into the newly defined `MyModel`'s instance which does not contain any layers, weights, etc., or the "right" `forward` method (... I'm assuming your actual `forward` method does not just `return` `0`).

So, we have to `import` `MyModel`, instantiate it, and then `load` the `state_dict` into the `model` instance; the rest of what you have is fine:

```
'''
# Do not re-define MyModel;
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return 0
'''
# instead, import MyModel from the file.py in which it is defined;
from MyModel_file_name import MyModel
def load_pytorch_model(PATH, **kwargs):
    '''
    Steps:
        (1): Load model_dict.
        (2): init MyModel(**kwargs).
        (3): Load state_dict into instance of MyModel.
        (4): model.eval() # optional
        (5): model.to(device='cuda:0') # optional
        (6): etc., ...
    
    Returns:
        instance of MyModel with loaded state_dict.
    '''
    def load_pytorch_model_state_dict(PATH):
        return torch.load(PATH)

    model_dict = load_pytorch_model_state_dict(PATH)
    model = MyModel(**kwargs)
    model.load_state_dict(model_dict)
    model.eval()
    #model.to(device='cuda:0')
    return model


model = load_pytorch_model(PATH)

example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
torch_script = torch.jit.trace(model, example_input)
```

and then if you `print(f'torch_script = {torch_script.__dict__}')` you should get something like:

```
torch_script = {'_non_persistent_buffers_set': set(), '_backward_pre_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_backward_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_is_full_backward_hook': None, '_forward_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_forward_hooks_with_kwargs': OrderedDict(), '_forward_hooks_always_called': OrderedDict(), '_forward_pre_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_forward_pre_hooks_with_kwargs': OrderedDict(), '_state_dict_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_state_dict_pre_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_load_state_dict_pre_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_load_state_dict_post_hooks': OrderedDict(), '_name': 'MultiDepthWiseConvAndFullyConnected', '_actual_script_module': RecursiveScriptModule(
  original_name=MultiDepthWiseConvAndFullyConnected
  (depthwise_layers_3x3): Sequential(
    original_name=Sequential
    (0): Conv2d(original_name=Conv2d)
    (1): BatchNorm2d(original_name=BatchNorm2d)
    (2): CustomLeakyReLU(original_name=CustomLeakyReLU)
    ....
   ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) for `Module.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=True, assign=False)`:

> Copies parameters and buffers from state_dict into this module and its descendants. If strict is True, then the keys of state_dict must exactly match the keys returned by this module’s state_dict() function.

Notice that `strict` is `True` by default, and there doesn't seem to be any registration of the container's state `dict`. Might want to make sure your `Module` container is preconfigured to recognize the state keys, or try setting `strict=False` when using `Module.load_state_dict`